# BusinessObjects 4.0 - Incompatible combination of tables

Tags: business-objects

In my BO universe there I intentionally left out contexts.
Now when I select measures from multiple fact tables I get following error msg:

> Incompatible combination of tables

Show details gives:

> Error:
>   com.businessobjects.semanticlayer.qt.QTException: The query cannot run because it contains incompatible objects.  (WIS 00008)
>   Cause of Error
>   The query cannot run because it contains incompatible objects.  (WIS 00008)
>   Cause of Error
>   Incompatible combination of tables

(btw - in the universe I have checked out the option "multiple SQL statements for each measure", which WAS checked by default)

Does anybody now how to resolve this error?

Second point - since I have intentionally removed contexts, that means there should be no loops in the data foundation. Right?
That also means that I should use Alias tables to remove every loop. Can somebody confirm this assumption?

And the last point is - I have 2 fact tables, and when I take both of them in the query panel, then I get one query -> one result. However I have additionally 2 fact tables, and when I take either one of them or both of them, I get 2 or 3 queries. Why is that happening, and where can I turn off generation of multiple queries? Thx!

Comment: In general, you will get the Incompatible error when you have selected objects from tables that have no join path between them.  Why are you not using contexts?  That's usually a given in a universe with multiple fact tables.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by (1) using alias tables, and (2) unchecking "multiple SQL statements for each measure"